# Delete action in a pageblocktable of wrapper list

Tags: wrapper-class, delete

I have a wrapper list in a pageblocktable, I need to add a delete action in that table which should delete or remove that particular wrapper record from the list.

My concern is it's a wrapper list, and which is bit saved yet. So how can I delete this on action delete. Is this possible by any means.

Code Snippet:

```
public void SelectedWrapperlist(){
        wUpdatedlist = new List<WrapDiscounts>();
        wRecord = new WrapDiscounts();

        wRecord.WrapPicklistOptions = getTypesOptions(); // 10  20  30  40
        Discounts = CustomClass1.findavailableDiscounts(applicableconditions);

        for(Discounts__c a : CustomClass1.findavailableDiscounts(applicableconditions)){
            WrapDiscounts i = new WrapDiscounts();
            i.WrapPicklistOptions  = getPicklistOptions();  // another method getting some records as list for picklist values
            i.wDiscountID = i.Id;
            i.wDiscountName = a.Name;
            i.wProdName = a.CustProduct__r.name;
            i.wProdType = a.Custom_Product_Type__c;
            wUpdatedlist.add(i);
        }
    }
```

This wrapper list I am getting requires some more processing to be done, so before saving this record. I am displaying this list in a pageblocktable

VF Page:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wUpdatedlist}" var="a">
    <apex:column headervalue="Id" value="{!a.Id}"/>
    <apex:column headervalue="Product Type" value="{!a.wProdType}"/>
    <apex:column headervalue="Product Name" value="{!a.wProdName}"/>
    <apex:column headervalue="Discount Name" value="{!a.wDiscountName}"/>
    <apex:column headervalue="Comments" value="{!a.Comments}"/>
    <apex:column>
     <!--- Command Like "Del" to delete that row. But not sure how to get the id of this row when it is not saved yet
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

I created a co..and button and called an arc method where am getting the row index to delete that row by

Integer.valueof(apex pages.currentpage().get parameters().get('rowindex'); but it's returning null error.

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's impossible to answer your question. There are ways to do what you ask. How, depends on the way you've implemented your wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an Integer variable say counter in your wrapper

```
public class WrapDiscounts{
        /* You would have defined many variables here
           along with that include this integer */
        public Integer counter{get;set;}
}
```

And increment this in your for loop where you are assigning values to Wrapper variables.

In VF Page, you can get the counter value on click of Delete link

```
<apex:column headerValue="Delete">
<apex:commandLink action="{!deleteRow}" styleClass="btn" value=" Delete ">
<apex:param assignTo="{!SelectedRowNumber}" value="{!a.counter}"/>
</apex:commandLink>
</apex:column>
```

Instead of declaring the counter variable in apex, you can do the iteration+increment in your vf page also, which ever suits you better.

Using apex:commandlink you can get the row's counter number on click event and you can style it to look like a button.

Now in the method "deleterow"

```
public void deleteRow() {
   wSelectedOfferings.remove(SelectedRowNumber);
}
```